# Is it possible to restrict ForceBindIP to only inbound/outbound traffic?

Tags: networking, winsock

I'm using [ForcebindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip)  to point an app at a specific network adapter, like this:

```
forcebindip -i 192.168.0.5  MyCSharpApp.exe
```

This works fine and the app isn't aware (or doesn't access) any of the other network adapters on the PC.

Is it possible to restrict `ForceBindIP` to outbound traffic only leaving the app to receive data from any local network adapter? Or even to specify a network adapter for outbound and another for inbound traffic?

I can't find an extra startup parameter for `ForceBindIP` that does this.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3):

*If I get your problem correctly, you want to bind your application to listen for packets on all available interfaces but return packets to only through one given interface. I also assume it's a server application and you don't have neiter source code nor control over its behaviour.*

**Disclosure:** I do not know how ForceBindIP works internally, I'm basing my understanding of it on this passage from the website:

> it will then inject a DLL (BindIP.dll) which loads WS2_32.DLL into memory and intercepts the bind(), connect(), sendto(), WSAConnect() and WSASendTo() functions, redirecting them to code in the DLL which verifies which interface they will be bound to and if not the one specified, (re)binds the socket

#### Problems to overcome

I don't believe your desired configuration is possible with just one application level DLL injector. I'll list a few issues that `ForceBindIP` will have to overcome to make it work:

1. to `listen` to a socket, application has to [bind()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind) it to a unique `protocol-address-port` combination first. An application can bind itself to either a specific address or a wildcard (i.e. listen on all interfaces). Apparently, one can bind to wildcard and specific address simultaneously as outlined in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618949/binding-to-same-port-using-inaddr-any-and-a-specific-ip-simultaneously). This however will be two different sockets from the application standpoint. Therefore your application will have to know how to handle this sort of traffic.
2. When accepting client connection, [accept()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept) will create a new socket and parameters on that are managed by Windows, I don't believe there's an API to intercept binding here - by this time the connection is considered established.
3. Now imagine, we somehow got a magic socket. We can receive packets on one interface and send to another. The client (and all routing equipment on the way) will have to be aware that two packets originating from two different source IP addresses are actually part of the same connection and be able to assemble the TCP session (or correctly merge UDP streams).

You can have multiple gefault gateways with different priorities and rules (which is a whole different topic to explore) but as far as I'm aware that's not going to solve your particular issue: majority of routing protocols assume links are symmetric and expect packets to keep within same interface. There are special cases like [asymmetric routing](https://www.cisco.com/web/services/news/ts_newsletter/tech/chalktalk/archives/200903.html) and [network interface teaming](https://superuser.com/questions/955825/is-windows-10-software-nic-teaming-now-possible/1391022) but they have to be implemented on per-interface level.

#### One potential solution

One way to achieve what you're after (I don't know enough about your environment to claim it will work), will be to create a [virtual interface](https://superuser.com/questions/1299022/creating-a-virtual-nic-that-connects-to-the-same-network-as-physical-nic), set it into yet another IP network, bind your application to it, then use firewall (to, say, allow multicast backets into the "virtual" network) and routing from that network to required default gateway with [metric set to 1](https://superuser.com/questions/1140216/cant-change-network-connection-priority-in-windows-10/1218446). I also suspect just any `Windows` will not be that flexible, so you might need like a `Server Edition`.

I am sorry this didn't turn out to be the ready-to-fly solution, I however am hoping this gives you more context to the problem you are facing and points you into other directions to explore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty command in Powershell to set the flow control of your specified adapter

To get the names and properties of all the network adapter :-

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "*"
```

Suppose you want the network adapter named "Ethernet 2" to be only used to receive data from internet then type :-

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Ethernet 2" -DisplayName "Flow Control" -DisplayValue "Rx Enabled"
```

You can find more in **:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/set-netadapteradvancedproperty?view=win10-ps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking to restrict traffic 'per process', not per adapter. So for a given process, use Ethernet 2 for outbound traffic, but allow the process to receive internal traffic (i.e. pipes or multi-cast sockets) from any adapter (including Ethernet 1).

Comment: This can be achived by windows firewall to block outbound traffic of specific process by setting outbound rules to block for disired process. Here is the link: https://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/

Comment: I'm looking for a solution with ForceBindIP, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: i doubt this setting is doing what you hope for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_flow_control

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft winsock example has a usage in their example for limiting a socket to only send or receive mode. It might help.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code

Outbount and Inbount limits are not imposed while binding. But latter or when connection is established.
Line of code pertaining to this in client code is toward the end.

`// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent`

`iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);`

Comment: I'm no C expert but I just fail to see how the line you mention is relevant to OP's problem. I also am a tad confused as this is client code and OP send to be running a listener? I guess where I'm going with this - do you mind elaborating a bit on your answer?